# AWS Pre-signed PUT URL Requires &s to be Replaced with &amp;?

Tags: url, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a service that generates S3 pre-signed PUT URLS for uploading.

While testing I noticed that Postman would have no issue uploading to the pre-signed URL as long as I clicked on the URL in "Pretty" mode.  This would put the URL in its address bar.

But when I copied the raw output, it would 403 every time.

Does AWS S3 require & signs to be replaced with `&amp;?`

**EDIT: Updating to show how pre-signed URL is fetched with Node/Express/AWS API**

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {Bucket: 'some-s3-bucket', Key: 'test/'};
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
        res.json({url: url});
    });
});
```

[image: This URL would produce a 403]

[image: Clicking on this replaces the & in the URL to &]

[image: This URL would work]

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't html-encode `&` → `&amp;` in the query string separators in an S3 signed URL.

It sounds like your service is generating the urls and either it, or something in the chain, is incorrectly html-encoding them, and by luck, postman or the browser is cleaning them back up again when you view them in "pretty" mode.

If you're deliberately doing this, then don't... but if you're unclear where the spurious encoding is coming from, switching to a text based tool for talking to your service -- like curl or wget -- is likely to get you closer to understanding what's going on than a browser-based tool.

Comment: I have double checked my code for fetching the pre-signed url.  From what I can tell there isn't anything weird going on.

Code to grab the s3 pre-signed URL:

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    var params = {Bucket: 'some-s3-bucket', Key: 'test/'};
    s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
        res.json({url: url});
    });
});

Comment: I still get the same behavior in both PostMan and programmatically.

Comment: @binarygiant are you saying that wheb you use `curl` from the command line, you still see `&amp;` in the response even though you are not deliberately adding it?